# C++ OpenMP lock istruction

Tags: c++, locking, openmp

I'm new using OpenMP, and I'm wondering if it is possible to lock a single instrucion inside a loop. 
In other words inside a for loop I have 5 instruction, lets say A,B,C,D and E. "C" must be executed with the lock (because it writes over a common resource) and the other istructions can be executed in parallel. Is there a way to achive this?

let me use pseudocode to clarify what I want to achive

```
#pragma omp parallel for
 for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    A;
    B;
    lock(C);
    D; 
    E;
 }
```

Comment: If `C` is a very simple operation (such as `C++;`), use `atomic`, otherwise, use a `critical` region.

Comment: Accept the below answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use critical before that lock so it ensures that the next line of code is executed by only one thread.
Definition of CRITICAL: The CRITICAL directive specifies a region of code that must be executed by only one thread at a time.

You can do like this.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    A;
    B;
    #pragma omp critical
    lock(C);
    D; 
    E;
}
```

Definition source: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/

Comment: If  "lock()" is really a simple statement like x += 1; you could use #pragma omp atomic, which is normally faster than a critical section since it exploits hardware capabilities better and usually does not use a lock internally.